# How to get caption below Fig x.y. and have control on the space separating the picture and the text

Tags: floats, captions

I need two things while inserting a picture in a document.

First, I want the caption text to also extend below the word, say Figure 1.1. In my case, below Figure 1.1. there is no text. The caption text is situated through many lines only to the right of Figure 1.1.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.43]{body/DBD}
    \caption{Scrutinizing three different membrane segments for checking for an enrichment        contact. We observe the three crossings through each of the three membrane segments, of which          one is the high-spot presumed to represent a reliable TJ contact between two neighboring cells. Adapted from \cite{traylor2010evolutionary}.}
 \label{DBD}
 \end{figure}
```

Second, I also need to have control on the distance between the picture (including the caption) and the text of the document.

What should I do?

Comment: see documentation of package `caption`. Run in a terminal or command window `texdoc caption`

Comment: You should improve your tags. What has your question to do with biblatex or overleaf?

Comment: You say "In my case, below Figure 1.1. there is no text.", then it is strongly recommended that you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show (the exact kind of output in) your case.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your question is not very clear. It can be guessed, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Scrutinizing three different membrane segments for checking for an enrichment        contact. We observe the three crossings through each of the three membrane segments, of which one is the high-spot presumed to represent a reliable TJ contact between two neighboring cells. Adapted from \cite{traylor2010evolutionary}.}
 \label{DBD}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```